# Summing then multiplying rows and columnar values in a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, multiplication

I have a 2 dimensional array like this

```
array(
    array(
        'column1' => 10,
        'column2' => 11
    ),
    array(
        'column1' => 25,
        'column2' => 137
    ),
    array(
        'column1' => 21,
        'column2' => 58
    )
)
```

The keys `column1` and `column2` are fixed. They do not change.

I need to perform various functions on the data in this 2D array. The various functions can be grouped in two ways:

- Row-wise first
- Column-wise first

An example for Row-wise first functions,

I want to sum up all the numbers row-wise first before multiplying by columns.

So the expected behavior is (10+11) * (25+137) * (21+58)

An example for Column-wise first functions,

I want to sum up all the numbers column-wise first before multiplying by rows.

So the expected behavior is (10+25+21)*(11+137+58)

I have no problems writing out my own component functions. In the above, I need only two component functions sum and product

```
function sum (adden1, adden2) {
    return adden1 + adden2;
}

function product (multiplicant1, multiplicant2) {
    return multiplicant1 * multiplicant2;
}
```

The problem is the mapping. I want to reduce the number of for-loops I need to write. I want my code to be more modular because there are situations where the required behaviors are like:

1. Perform this for each row 100-(column1+column2) / column2 and then sum up all the results.

There are too many formulae I need to work. But I am very confident that basically it is all a mixture of either performing row-wise first or column-wise first.

Hope to get some suggestions on the mapping of the values to the functions.

**UPDATE:**

Eventually I redesign my architecture to make this issue go away. So this question no longer is applicable to me.

Comment: I don't think so, it can be done without `for OR foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Row wise is the easiest to map:

```
$a = array(
    array(
        'column1' => 10,
        'column2' => 11
    ),
    array(
        'column1' => 25,
        'column2' => 137
    ),
    array(
        'column1' => 21,
        'column2' => 58
    )
);

echo array_product(array_map('array_sum', $a)), "\n";
```

Column wise needs a utility function to grab all columns together into one array:

```
echo array_product(array(
  array_sum(array_column($a, 'column1')),
  array_sum(array_column($a, 'column2'))
)), PHP_EOL;

function array_column(array $a, $column)
{
  return array_map(function($item) use ($column) {
    return $item[$column];
  }, $a);
}
```

Comment: I like your code better than bmused. But I like that bmused put the links to array_map and array_walk. I didn't know those functions exist.

Comment: @kimsia yes, linking to the manual is convenient :) just type "php.net/" followed by any function name to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate over the array somehow. Take a look at [array_map](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php).

Here's an example:

```
<?php
$input = array(
    array(
        'column1' => 10,
        'column2' => 11
    ),
    array(
        'column1' => 25,
        'column2' => 137
    ),
    array(
        'column1' => 21,
        'column2' => 58
    )
);

echo 'Row wise : ', array_product(array_map(
    function($row){ 
     return $row['column1'] + $row['column2']; 
    }, $input)), '<br/>';

$output = array(0,0);
array_walk($input, 
  function($val, $key, &$output){ 
     $output[0] += $val['column1'];
     $output[1] += $val['column2'];
  }, &$output);
echo 'Column wise : ', array_product($output);


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the orientation of your 2d array, making mapped calls of `array_sum()` then a single call to `array_product()` is the most concise functional-style approach.

To process row-wise, pass the original array to the aforementioned process.

To process column-wise, simply "transpose" your array -- in other words convert your columnar data into rows. Typically, the preferred approach is also the most concise: `array_map(null, ...$array)`. HOWEVER, if you ever have just one row of data in your 2d array, then only a 1d array will be produced and that will break the aforementioned process which requires a 2d array.  For this reason, choose a transposing technique that is stable.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/vDHHv))

```
$array = [
    ['column1' => 10, 'column2' =>  1],
    ['column1' => 3, 'column2' => 5],
    ['column1' => 2, 'column2' =>  4]
];

// multiply summed rows (10+1)×(3+5)×(2+4) = 528
echo array_product(
         array_map(
             'array_sum',
             $array
         )
     );
echo "\n---\n";
// multiply summed column (10+3+2)×(1+5+4) = 150
echo array_product(
         array_map(
             'array_sum',
             array_map(
                 fn(...$cols) => $cols,
                 ...$array
             )
         )
     );
```